# Invalid date provided: Invalid Date

Tags: javascript, angular, flatpickr

I got the following error
**form.min.js:1 Error: Invalid date provided: Invalid Date
at Object.parseDate (form.min.js:1)**

And I am using the flatpickr to pick the date in the input field.

If anyone has the solution please share it with me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Please share code to get proper suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Example,

```
var testDate;
var expDate = 04/08/2022;

testDate = new Date(expDate.substr(6, 4), expDate.substr(3, 2) - 1, expDate.substr(0, 2))
```

It works for me!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're supplying defaultDate to the calendar, like initial value? If you're getting a problem there, check if you're passing the value in the right format: https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/ for example:

**Date Object**

```
new Date(2015, 0, 10)
```

**Timestamp**

```
1488136398547
```

**ISO Date Strings**

```
"2017-02-26T19:40:03.243Z"
```

Console log the value you're passing to the component to check the actual format.